# Can I make my local webapp visible to a friend by an ip?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJs and so I'm wondering: can I to look my work to a friend, giving him an ip? Probably AngularJs doesn't count, I'm using a simple "web server" via NodeJs. Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to expose my localhost to the WWW? (port forwarding?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717426/how-to-expose-my-localhost-to-the-www-port-forwarding)

Comment: That also depends on your network setup e.g. Firewall. But the first place you should look at is to make your NodeJS HTTP server listen for any IPs like this: `.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0')`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes It can be done, by using https://meetfinch.com/. Use node package manager to install finch, create an account and forward your site. It will give you a url xyz.usefinch.com. Just share with your friend and enjoy.

It creates a secure connection between your computer and your friends computer without any external servers and the traffic is also encrypted.

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: "It creates a secure connection between your computer and your friends computer without any external servers" - the homepage makes it pretty clear this is not the case.  Finch's servers are in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a tunneling service such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)