# Web page that shows a video stream from a local server

Tags: html, video-streaming

I am streaming video in http://localhost:8080/foo, and I want to add this stream to my webpage to see it locally, tried to use the `<video>` and doesn't work and the `<img>` tag to.

What are my option to solve this problem in HTML5 (I dont know the type of video that is streaming and the address from before is a video server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you could simply use html5 video facility which is being used by youtube it is can be very simple done and almost all the browsers support this feature of html5. Just use this code:`

```
<video>
  <source src="(url from web root).(video extension)" type="video/(the video extension)">
</video>
```

The modifications you should make is so simple all that requires is the document root to the video with its name and its extension(which can be got by right clicking on the respected video and selecting properties option).

Just copy and paste with the modifications done into your page and see the awesome stuff.

Also never use the img tag for videos as pictures (except giff) will not animate.....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand - you are trying to expose localhost so your presumably remote web server can stream the video?

Answered here [How to expose my localhost to the WWW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717426/how-to-expose-my-localhost-to-the-www-port-forwarding)