# npm ngrok : Is it safe to use?

Tags: node.js, react-native, ngrok

I stumbled across `ngrok` while trying to find a way to connect to my localhost API through my android device.

I have a question, is using `ngrok` safe or not ? If not, then what all threats does it posses ?

Comment: Yes -- it is safe, and it is encrypted end-to-end. If you don't trust it, there are open source alternatives available.

Comment: Thanks MrSaints !!..Can you tell me another alternative for it?

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/secure-localhost-tunnels-with-ngrok/

Comment: Google `site:github.com expose http tunnel`. There's quite a few.

Comment: Thanks MrSaints & Vishwas Nahar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ngrok safe to use or can it be compromised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552950/is-ngrok-safe-to-use-or-can-it-be-compromised)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `ngrok` is safer to use.

`ngrok` provides a tunnelling so that your local-hosted server can be accessed from outside the machine over the internet.

Comment: Does it matter which port you use?  Is it best to use some random port like 3848 or is it okay to use a rounded number like 5000?