# how to access gitlab server from internet which is installed in local server

Tags: git, port, forwarding

I have gitlab server installed in a server (local server) which contain private ip address only. Now I want to access this gitlab from internet using port forwarding process. I do have gateway server which have public ip as well as private ip. Can any one help how to access local server for git using gateway server from internet. I tried using prerouting/postrouting rules in iptables of gateway server but no luck.

Comment: Either you need a VPN on the gateway server, or port forwarding + NAT, or a tunnel. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4717426/7976758), [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=expose+internet+server+local+address).

Comment: i would like to use port forwarding + NAT and trying to resolve the issue but not yet success. Any suggestion for port forwarding + NAT.

Comment: `no luck` is not enough. What kernel version is on gateway? How did you configure `iptables`? Is forwarding enabled? Have you read [instructions](https://serverfault.com/a/140626)? Have you tried to watch packets with `tcpdump` trying to debug at what stage packets are dropped?…